# How to scan input string for token stream

Tags: c, tokenize

I'm doing a simple Lexical Analyzer C program. What I want to do first is to tokenize the inputted statement. (Example statement: printf1234=---abc)

How will I separate "printf", "1234", "=", "---", and "abc" using strtok()?

Here's my experimental code for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    char input_string[100];
    char string_storage[100][100];
    char *token;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(input_string);

    token = strtok(input_string, " ");
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",token);
        //strcpy(input_storage,token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: space is not a delimiter...so why do you use that?

Comment: `strtok` depends on there being a delimiter (or set of delimiters) between your tokens; for your specific example string, `strtok` is not the correct tool.

Comment: Don't use strtok for token parsing, it's better to build a token parser by hand.

Comment: Adding to @JohnBode comment, i strongly feel you've to write your own functions (employing **regex**) to achieve what you wish to do..

Comment: Since my instructor will input random statement like "abc++scanf=printf", therefore delimiters are of no use. I'm confused though as what kind of delimiter should I use to tokenize this kind of statement and to separate "abc", "++", "scanf", "=", "printf"

Comment: First, make sure you understand what constitute valid tokens for input. From the looks of it, you have operators (`+`, `=`, etc) and identifiers (`abc`, `scanf`, `printf`, etc). `strtok` does not help you here because it expects a specific form in which each thing you are interested in is separated by the *same delimeter*. (For example, you could use `strtok` to get the strings out of a comma separated list.) In your case, you have to start reading characters and accumulating an identifier until you see an operator, etc. Or use regex. This is the *scanning* phase.

Comment: If a valid identifier can be a string starting with a letter and containing letters or numbers, then `printf1234` will be ambiguous. It could be scanned as `printf` (identifier) and `1234` (a number), or it could be just an identifier, `printf1234`.

Comment: I've actually written functions to identify, integers, identifier, and operators, and store them in its designated storage. however, I'm having problems with Keywords (i.e printf, scanf).

Comment: Do you have a dictionary of keywords? Scanning keywords should be the same as scanning identifiers (unless your keywords don't match the identifier description). You can scan it as an identifier then check against your dictionary to determine if it's a keyword.

Comment: I only have to scan "printf" and "scanf" for now.

Comment: Right. But for good coding practice (*e.g.*, thinking about the future), you want a dictionary which is just an array of strings at this point. Maybe it just has two elements for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have understood by now `strtok` you can't use over here.Because you can't use a specific delimiter set for the input. Or even if you can then it wouldn't be good enough to have a generic tokenizer.

What you can do is, simply decide first what token would be? That way you will have some set of lexical rules that will decide the tokens. For example 4 digit numbers will be a token, `=` will be another one and so on. Then you will have a set of rules of getting the tokens. Until this, it was much easier. This problem is already solved. You can apply those solutions yourself.

This is known as lexical analysis is compiler design. There is no meaning associated in here. As you didn't mention about anything semantical you can as well stop here. [`lex`](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/) maybe you can look at this and get some idea. If this is not needed or in this detail you don't need then you have to create some automata which will do that for you. (Regex processing is what you will do).

An interesting discussion regarding this can be found in Dragon Book. Go through it - if you want to dig deeper.

Comment: thank you. That's the best thing I should do for now since my only problem is to separate the keywords (scanf, printf). :)

Answer (score 3):

strtok is about doing a **spatial** subdivision on the basis of a delimiter. Here you don't have a clear delimeter. You are looking for a **semantic** subvision, which is based on the type of content you expect to have in each token. You should take a look at **regex** theory for this. You should now the constraints of your input statement for example you have a textual command, then numbers, then always a = sign, etc..

Comment: Strictly speaking, using standard compiler construction parlance, I don't think the OP is at the *semantic* level yet. The OP needs a general *scanner* for breaking an input stream into tokens (to "tokenize the input" as they say). A stream of tokens is then *parsed* (*e.g.*, into a parse tree) and then *semantics* applied.

Comment: Yep, strictly speaking you are right, the word semantic can be misleading. The idea is to give some common sense idea to make her understand the difference between delimiter and pattern search.

Comment: If the OP decides to study some industry textbooks on the topic and encounters semantic analysis, I just didn't want them to be confused by this. :)

Comment: And now you have [two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).